# Query to Calculate totalcost based on description

Tags: sql, oracle

I have question regarding sql script. I have a custom view, below is the data

```
================================================================================
ql_siteid | ql_rfqnum | ql_vendor | ql_itemnum | totalcost_option | description
================================================================================
SGCT      | 1002      | VND001    | ITEM002    | 12500            |
SGCT      | 1002      | VND001    | ITEM001    | 1350             |
SGCT      | 1002      | VND002    | ITEM002    | 11700            |
SGCT      | 1002      | VND002    | ITEM001    | 1470             | Nikon
SGCT      | 1002      | VND002    | ITEM001    | 1370             | Asus
================================================================================
```

And i want the result like below table:

```
VND001 = 13850 
VND002 = Asus 13070, Nikon 13170
```

where 13850 is come from 12500+1350, 13070 is come from 11700+1370 and 13170 is come from 11700+1470. All the cost is calculated from totalcost_option and will be group based on vendor

So please give me some advise

Comment: Oracle version is going to be important here. 11g+? Also, where does the currency code come from?

Comment: yes, 11g. For the currency it will be base currency in the table. As long as i can achieve like Asus 13070, Nikon 13170 that would be great, so the currency is not very critical here.

Comment: No logic to `group` the query.If it has `n` items what you will do.

Comment: the grouping will be based on the vendor, and if 1 vendor has n item with 1 item has description, but the rest do not have, then it should be calculated. so for instance is VND002 has 1 additional ITEM (totalcost_option 1000) but the description is null, the result should be: VND002 = Asus 14070, Nikon 14170, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a version of Oracle 11g or later, using [ListAgg](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions100.htm#SQLRF30030) will do the combination of the comma separated tuples for you. The rest of the string is generated by simply concatenating the components together from an intermediate table - I've used a derived table (X) here, but you could also use a CTE.

**Edit**

As pointed out in the comments, there's a whole bunch more logic missing around the Null description items I missed in my original answer.

The following rather messy query does project the required result, but I believe this may be indicative that a table design rethink is necessary. The `FULL OUTER JOIN` should ensure that rows are returned even if there are no base / descriptionless cost items for the vendor.

```
WITH NullDescriptions AS
(
  SELECT "ql_vendor", SUM("totalcost_option") AS "totalcost_option"
  FROM MyTable
  WHERE "description" IS NULL
  GROUP BY "ql_vendor"
),
NonNulls AS
(
  SELECT COALESCE(nd."ql_vendor", mt."ql_vendor") AS "ql_vendor", 
         NVL(mt."description", '') || ' '
         || CAST(NVL(mt."totalcost_option", 0) 
                    + nd."totalcost_option" AS VARCHAR2(30)) AS Combined
  FROM NullDescriptions nd
  FULL OUTER JOIN MyTable mt
    ON mt."ql_vendor" = nd."ql_vendor"
    AND mt."description" IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT x."ql_vendor" || ' = ' || ListAgg(x.Combined, ', ') 
                                       WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY x.Combined)
FROM NonNulls x
WHERE x.Combined <> ' '
GROUP BY x."ql_vendor";
```

[Updated SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2bc48/36)

Comment: Not sure Stuart, but the output for your query is different from what Ferdi has asked in the question.

Comment: Thanks stuart, this is exactly what i'm looking for. Why i didn't think of this recursive sql. Once again thanks mate..!!!

Answer (score 1):

To get the exact output you required use the following statement: (where test_table is your table name):

```
SELECT ql_vendor || ' = ' || 
       LISTAGG( LTRIM(description||' ')||totalcost, ', ')
       WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY description)
FROM (
  WITH base_cost AS (
    SELECT ql_vendor, SUM(totalcost_option) sumcost
    FROM test_table WHERE description IS NULL
    GROUP BY ql_vendor
  ),
  individual_cost AS (
    SELECT ql_vendor, totalcost_option icost, description
    FROM test_table WHERE description IS NOT NULL
  )
  SELECT ql_vendor, sumcost + NVL(icost,0) totalcost, description
  FROM base_cost LEFT OUTER JOIN individual_cost USING (ql_vendor)
)
GROUP BY ql_vendor;
```

Details:

The Outer select just takes the individual rows and combines them to the String-representation. Just remove it and you will get a single row for each vendor/description combination.

The inner select joins two sub-select. The first one gets the base_cost for each vendor by summing up all rows without a description. The second gets the individual cost for each row with a description.

The join combines them - and left outer joins displays the base_cost for vendors which don't have a matching row with description.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic seems to be:  If `description` is always `NULL` for a vendor then you want that as the total cost.  Otherwise, you want the `NULL` value of description added to all the other values.  The following query implements this logic.  The output is in a different format from your answer -- this format is more consistent with a SQL result set:

```
select ql_vendor,
       (sum(totalcost_option) +
        (case when description is not null then max(totalcost_null) else 0 end)
       )
from (select v.*, max(description) over (partition by ql_vendor) as maxdescription,
             sum(case when description is null then totalcost_option else 0 end)  over (partition by ql_vendor) as totalcost_null
      from view v
     ) t
where maxdescription is null or description is not null
group by ql_vendor, description;
```